# Predicate for Child to parent entity using NSFetchResultController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities `A` and `B`. `A` has one-to-many relationship with `B`. Now I want to fetch entity B using `NSFetchResultController`. If entity `A` has more than one `B`, I should get only one `B` while fetching. Can somebody tell me how to use predicate for this fetch?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement some more?  Do you need to use an FRC rather than a straight fetch?  If so, why?  And why would you only want one B for each A?  And if there is more than one B for a given A, which B would you like included?

Comment: I have to use FRC. If there is more than one B for a given A, the B with the latest created date(an attribute) would be included.

Comment: Do you need the FRC to provide sections (ie. are you using the sectionNameKeyPath)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a FRC. Even if you could it wouldn't do the update notifications correctly when the model changed so is pointless anyway.

So you either have to

a) fetch, filter and sort manually to get your source data. You can observe `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` to know when to refresh.

b) cache this information into a seperate property so it is accessible to the FRC. ie B needs to independently know if it should be displayed.